# Paypal API Subscription Create returns 400 Bad Request response "name", though request is formed as in documentation

Tags: laravel, api, paypal

I try to implement Paypal subscription service according to: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

This is my first try.

In sandbox business account I have created two test subscriptions: monthly and yearly and configured application with their id's.

This is the method:

```
public function createSubscription($planSlug, $name, $email) {
    return $this->makeRequest(
        'POST',
        'v1/billing/subscriptions',
        [],
        [
            'plan_id' => $this->plans[$planSlug],
            'subscriber' => [
                'name' => [
                    'given_name' => $name,
                ],
                'email_address' => $email
            ],
            'application_context'=> [
                'brand_name' => config('app.name'),
                'shipping_preference' => 'NO_SHIPPING',
                'user_action' => 'SUBSCRIBE_NOW',
                'return_url' => route('subscribe.approval', ['plan' => $planSlug]),
                'cancel_url'=> route('subscribe.cancelled')
            ],
        ],
        [],
        $isJsonRequest = true
    );
}
```

However, when I make a call to API, to create a test subscription, I get weird response that 'name' parameter is formed incorrectly:

```
php artisan tinker

>>> $paypal = resolve(App\Services\PaypalService::class);
=> App\Services\PaypalService {#3413}
>>> $paypal->createSubscription('monthly', 'Test', 'test@test.com');

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException with message 'Client error: `POST https://api- 
m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or 
violates schema.","debug_id (truncated...)
```

This is strange, because in Paypal API doc (see above), the 'name' param is described exactly like that!

Do I miss something or it is Paypal API is acting funky?

Comment: Recently I was testing their buttons and they glitched. They charged a customer without their approval first. Their subscriptions are another issue I've dealt with too, and their webhooks are something else. You should probably try again.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
try {
  // your code here
} catch(\Throwable $th) {
  if ($th instanceof ClientException) {
     $r = $th->getResponse();
     $responseBodyAsString = json_decode($r->getBody()->getContents());
     dd($responseBodyAsString);
  }
}
```

I've faced this too before and it was not easy for me to figure out how to show an explicit error message.

Answer (score 0):

'return_url' => route('subscribe.approval', ['plan' => $planSlug]),
'cancel_url'=> route('subscribe.cancelled')

the problem is in this two url, may be you have changed the APP_URL in the .env

APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

put app url that and try